# why not cycle type of a permutation are just x 2 cycles?

Tags: abstract-algebra

going through Prof. Macauley 's Algebra class [cycle type and conjugacy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H7qHhSs9rG8&list=PLwV-9DG53NDxU337smpTwm6sef4x-SCLv&index=17). in the previous cycle group classes, it is mentioned that every element $\sigma$ of $S_n$ could be decomposed into consecutive 2 cycles. so isn't cycle type of a permutation just a bunch of 2 cycles?

Comment: The cycle type is defined for a product of *disjoint* cycles.

Comment: @Marktmeister https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Cycle_type_of_a_permutation I am reading it is defined for a permutation

Comment: oh, you mean disjoint cycles. I get it now.

Comment: ... and how is cycle decomposition defined? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Different representations are convenient at different times.

One popular representation of a permutation is into disjoint cycles.  So, one example is $(123)(45)$.  The representation is not unique e.g. $(231)(54)$ is the same permutation but it is easy to recognize which are the same.

Another popular representation is into transpositions (2-cycles).  The previous example in this style is $(13)(23)(45)$.  Note that these 2-cycles are not disjoint, $2$ appears in two of them.  This will be occur unless the previous representation contained only 2-cycles.  The representation will not be unique and it may be less obvious which ones represent the same permutation.  Although this representation is not unique, an interesting feature is that if one representation of a permutation contains an even number of transpositions then any other representation of the same permutation will.  Similarly for odd.  As a result, we can call a permutation even if one of its representations in this form is even.  This is well defined since if one representation is even then any other will be as well.  The even permutations form a sub-group and is commonly written $A_n$.

Slightly counterintuitive is that a 3-cycle is even.  E.g. $(123)$ is $(13)(23)$ in that form.